# Delphi - como tratar delete no relacionamento master-detail?

Tags: delphi, firedac

Tenho duas tabelas usando Firedac TFDTable e fiz o relacionamento Master-Detail entre elas o qual funciona bem. No forms tenho dois DBgrids, um para cada tabela , ao apagar um registro no DBgrid Master gostaria que ele apagasse automaticamente os registros correspondentes no Dbgrid detalhe, com um aviso de exclusão antes de apagar, para que o usuário confirme sua intenção.
Como fazer esta validação e operação de delete ?
Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, mas não recomendo. Na verdade não recomendo trabalhar com *Tables*, é muito amarrado e limita bastante vários aspectos técnicos que podem ser melhorados na aplicação. Mas isso fica a critério de cada um, é apenas uma opinião pessoal.
Nesse [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Caching_Updates_(FireDAC)) há a explicação oriunda da **Embarcadero** de como fazer o que você quer.
Em suma você deve seguir os seguintes passos:

- Soltar um `TFDSchemaAdapter` em um formulário.
- Defina a propriedade `SchemaAdapter` do *dataset mestre* para o
  `TFDSchemaAdapter`.
- Definir a propriedade `SchemaAdapter` do *dataset detalhe* para o
  `TFDSchemaAdapter`.
- Definir a propriedade `FetchOptions.DetailCascade` do *dataset detalhe*  para `True`.

Outra possibilidade que acho mais conveniente é por meio de ***foreign keys cascade***.

Comment: Andrey, obrigado. Vou estudar esta proposta e prototipar um forms para avaliar o funcionamento.  Depois respondo com o resultado.

Comment: Andrey, conclui o teste. Coloquei as configurações descritas no link acima  , fiz passo a passo num form de teste, mas NÃO FUNCIONOU , pois ao tentar apagar um registro no DBgrid Master, o qual tinha filhos retornou o erro [FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-0922: integrity constraint (JRG.Depto_Emp_FK) violated - child record found.   Alterei também a propriedade do FDQueryEmp (detail)  DetailServerCascade = true , mas nada mudou !  Agradeo se puderem me ajudar !

Comment: Importante : neste teste usei FDQuery ao invés de FDTable, mesmo assim não funciona !

Comment: Descobri que faltou eu configurar a proppriedade  CacheUpdates=True nos dois datasets.  Agora FUNCIONOU o delete cascade entre um DBgrid Master e um DBGrid detail !  Andrey , obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Além da possibilidade já descrita anteriormente também pode fazer 'manualmente', através do evento *BeforeDelete* da *TFDTable* **master** e colocar a mensagem de confirmação e um loop para apagar as linhas do **detail** como por exemplo:

```
detail.DisableControls;
While detail.Locate('idpai',masterid.value,[]) do 
    detail.delete;
detail.EnableControls;
```

Pode dar mais trabalho mas permite ter mais controlo.

Comment: Tiago, entendi a proposta.  Vou simular e depois respondo o que ocorreu. Obrigado, por enquanto !